# The BBC has shown me very little respect

Tags: adverbs, determiners

> *The BBC has shown me very little respect.*

What is the determiner of the noun phrase *very little respect*?

Is it *little* or *very little*?

If it's *little* the adverb *very* seems to be modifying the determiner *little*.

Can an adverb modify a determiner in general?

Answer (score 4):

Larry Zweir, at [Cambridge Grammar and Beyond](http://www.cambridge.org/grammarandbeyond/grammar-practice-activities/2015/12/compound-quantifiers-alternatives-to-much-and-many) (abridged and reformatted), classes

1. a lot of
2. a great deal of
3. a large amount of
4. quite a few
5. a little bit of
6. a small number of
7. a small amount of

as **compound quantifiers**.

All except (1) here can obviously have an intensifier / downtoner removed to leave a more basic compound quantifier. (This makes significant differences in all but (2).)

So 'very little', though no noun seems involved, can arguably be classed as a compound quantifier (with the simple quantifier 'little'), and hence a determiner.

Obviously, some will prefer to separate parts here, and talk about 'quantifier modifiers' by whatever name they prefer.

Comment: Isn't *a **whole** lot of...* an "intensifier"? That's still current, even if we wouldn't usually use alternatives such as ***fine, good*** in such contexts today.

Comment: As I say. And 'a _small_ amount of' illustrates downtoning. Some may label 'small' a downtoner, some leave it as part of a larger lexeme.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So in general an adverb cannot modify a determiner?

Comment: There are no agreed single definitions for 'word' and 'sentence', so you can imagine that different schools treat _this_ issue differently. Zweir gives one analysis. I prefer this sort of lumping (though the lump-or-split debate certainly has examples where a preferred model is seen to have drawbacks). _Beware answers lacking 'according to ...'_.